# If the past is infinite, then I couldn't have reached the present, since the countdown to my arrival would never end

Tags: time, paradox

If there's an infite past, it would take an infinite time to reach this point. The countdown to my arrival would never stop, and so I would never arrive.

I did arrive. Conclusion: past events are finite in temporal expansion.

Comment: [Zeno's Paradoxes](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/paradox-zeno/)

Comment: [The Beginning of Time?](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/the-myth-of-the-beginning-of-time-2006-02/): "String theory suggests that the BIG BANG was not the origin of the universe but simply the outcome of a preexisting state."

Comment: This is the same fallacy as in the [Achilles and the Tortoise](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/paradox-zeno/#AchiTort). Achilles does catch up to the tortoise nonetheless. And whether time is finite or infinite is just a matter of measuring convention, we can rescale it so that finite intervals according to our current convention are infinite and vice versa. Such rescaling happens even under the standard conventions for local times of observers near black holes.

Comment: Ill-formed: you assume you've existed forever. If you would do the same with space, you'll occupy the whole universe. Wrong. You (and me) are a dot in space, and in time.

Comment: Conifold nailed it. This is one of Zeno's paradoxes.

Comment: I don't believe the OP is describing Zeno's paradox. They're talking about the case where Achilles has to travel an infinite distance at finite speed, not merely an infinitely divisible finite distance.

Comment: What if you counted down really fast though

Comment: Look at it the other way, if we were to travel back to the start, we could count as high as we like and never get there, which implies the start of the universe is infinitely far away.  Infinity is not a number.

Comment: This is more similar to Kants Antinomies than to Zeno's Paradoxes.

Comment: The problem is that you're trying to "count" time as it passes. Imagine the line y=x. Even though there are infinitely many point along the line between 0 and 1, the line nevertheless reaches 1 from 0 and continues on.

Comment: "it would take an infinite time to reach this point."  Huh? From **when** would it take an infinite amount of time to reach this point??? I don't believe there is any point of time from which it would have taken an infinite amount of time to reach the present.

Comment: From what number does this countdown begin?

Comment: 7

"It would take an infinite time to reach this point"...reach it from where? Exactly. It wouldn't start from anywhere if the past is sequentially infinite.

Comment: What if time is finite in some regions of reality, but infinite in others?

Comment: your proposition has the implicit assumption that time can only increment, a finite amount at a time. What if there are phenomena, which can make time increment at infinitely large intervals at  time? ( Like, say, A Black Hole)

Answer (score 7):

"It would take an infinite time to reach this point"...reach it from where? By assuming a countdown you assume a point where the countdown begins, i.e. a beginning of time, and so your argument is circular.

Whether or not time is infinite is an empirical question. It's logically possible that there is no first point in time, just as there is no smallest integer

Comment: Are you looking for "smallest nonzero real number" or "most negative integer"? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer

Comment: There is a smallest integer.

Comment: despite what your computer might think -2147483648 isn't in fact the smallest integer

Comment: @BurnsBA what's the smallest integer?

Comment: I am a mathematician, and I chose the words "smallest" and "integer" with their mathematical meanings, e.g. -2 is an integer, and -3 is a smaller integer. Given any integer, one may construct a smaller integer by subtracting one from it. Hence, there is no smallest integer.

Answer (score 3):

If a number line extends infinitely in either direction, that does not prevent us from using finite numbers, even though you cannot count from the lowest possible value to the highest possible value (or even from one set value to the lowest/highest possible value).

We can still use finite references in an infinite line, why wouldnt that work with time?  You arent measuring time in relation to some absolute beginning, just relative to other events.

Answer (score 2):

This is, as Kant explains in his discourse on antinomies of space and time, a natural line of argument against an infinite past. The problem is that an equally natural line of argument can apparently be conjured for the opposite conclusion, viz. that past time must be infinite (since an empty time would for *ex nihilo, nihil fit* reasons not give rise to any determinate change of its (absent) content).

So one might be a dialethist and conclude that time is *both* finite and infinite as to its past extent. Kant's conclusion, though, was that there is a subtle premise being omitted in such arguments, the premise that space and time are determinate wholes of some sort. One can read Kant as offering not a paraconsistent, but a para*complete*, picture of the extent of past time and the "edge" of outer space: if the forms of intuition (forms of givable particulars) are not transcendentally real, then their object, the "whole" world, is either determinately not a whole or is indeterminately a whole.

Answer (score 1):

No. You could make the exact same argument even if there were a finite past. So long as time is continuous you get the exact same result (suppose the universe is 10,000 years old but continuous, i.e. any unit of time can be further divided– so any traversal of some unit of time will require half of that and half of that and half of that...So, how could we have arrived at this moment!?). It follows that you "arriving" at a certain time is no evidence for whether time before was infinite or finite.

Further, contemporary physics seems to have a clean way of dealing with the issue of "beginning the count". We live in a (at least) four dimensional universe. Literally construed, it means that time is a dimension within a 4-dimensional manifold that just exists. Time is "within" it, so it doesn't even make sense to utter phrases like "counting down".

But suppose your argument is against the continuity of time. The generic response would be the generic response to Zeno's paradox: the formalization of the notion of the limit in calculus. The limit of adding these infinite intervals reaches your desired outcome of a specific unit. Of course, it is a controversial matter of whether calculus does resolve Zeno's paradox.

Answer (score 0):

Infinity is not a number. It's a process. As long as time continues in a forward direction the "present" is not a fixed number and the "distance" from past to present is not fixed but is always increasing. This is how time can be described as infinite. Even if the past began at zero, time (the present) continues to increase in an unending process.

When the process of time stops, the timeline becomes finite.

Answer (score -1):

I am re-writing.  I can do better than I did.

If we explore an eternal reality, within which we are existing "NOW!"...
... It has taken an eternity to get to now, but... an eternity will unfold in the future.

"NOW" is halfway between two halves of 1 whole eternal eternity.

You exist now.  You are an emergent phenomenon.  You did not always exist, and you will not exist forever.  You get a bunch of trips around the Sun... then die.  Like a hundred billion before you, and another 8 billion inevitably headed that direction.

"The countdown to me being is infinite"?

Well yes, eternal history precedes your current existence.  There is no logical problem there.  No issue.  You are a "NOW" and temporary emergent phenomenon."The future" is an eternity before you.  "The past" is eternity before you.

You, me, Earth, the Sun... all here "NOW" all smack dab in the middle of the two halves of eternity.

Not equally so, of course.  You and I will end before the Earth.  The Earth will probably end before or with the Sun.

Same shit... different time scales.

You are not eternal.  You emerged.  (Mommy moment).

All of the math adds up.  Because emergent phenomenon can (and do) have limited durations.

If that doesn't help, let me know, I will work on it till it does.

Comment: 7

"It would take an infinite time to reach this point"...reach it from where? Exact my point. It woulnd't be reached from anywhere if the past is sequentially infinite. Infinite loop is compatible with infinity though